# While downloading file from Azure Blob Storage using Golang getting " curl Empty reply from server" , but file is downloaded in background

Tags: azure, go, swagger, swagger-2.0, goroutine

I am trying to download a file from Azure Blob Storage using http request. I am able to download the file but on a terminal curl returns "Empty reply from server". I tried to increase the timeout, but it didn't fix it. I referred other questions related to this response from curl, but it didn't help. For small files this code is working flawlessly but for big files say 75 MB it is not working.

```
    containerURL := azblob.NewContainerURL(*URL, pipeline)

    blobURL := containerURL.NewBlockBlobURL(splitArray[1])

    ctx := context.Background()

    downloadResponse, err := blobURL.Download(ctx, 0, azblob.CountToEnd, azblob.BlobAccessConditions{}, false)

    if err != nil {
    .
    .
    .
    }

    bodyStream := downloadResponse.Body(azblob.RetryReaderOptions{MaxRetryRequests: 20})

    // read the body into a buffer
    downloadedData := bytes.Buffer{}

    _, err = downloadedData.ReadFrom(bodyStream)

    file, err := os.OpenFile(

        "/tmp/"+fileName,

        os.O_RDWR|os.O_TRUNC|os.O_CREATE,

        0777,
    )

    file.Write(downloadedData.Bytes())

    file.Close()

    filePath := "/tmp/" + fileName

    file, err = os.Open(filePath)

    return middleware.ResponderFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r runtime.Producer) {

        fn := filepath.Base(filePath)

        w.Header().Set(CONTENTTYPE, "application/octet-stream")

        w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf("attachment; filename=%q", fn))

        io.Copy(w, file)

        err := defer os.Remove(filePath)

        file.Close()

    })
```

I am thinking of implementing the above logic using goroutines. Is there even a need of using goroutines?

Any constructive feedback will be helpful.

Comment: Since you mentioned that larger files are not working could it be an issue with ctx timeout? Is there a default timeout which you need to override?

Comment: // TryTimeout indicates the maximum time allowed for any single try of an HTTP request.
    // A value of zero means that you accept our default timeout. NOTE: When transferring large amounts
    // of data, the default TryTimeout will probably not be sufficient. You should override this value
    // based on the bandwidth available to the host machine and proximity to the Storage service

This is from the [doc](https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob#RetryOptions)

Comment: @poWar Yes I tried with increasing timeout like I set it for 100 sec but say 3-4 times I got response empty reply from server and 2 times file got downloaded. I also tried increasing timeout to 3600sec (not good thing to do) but still there was inconsistency.

Comment: Okay. In that case, am not sure what could be the issue. Will have to wait for someone with experience on this to reply.

Comment: It also depends on consistency of your network, how long does it normally take to download. If your internet speed is fluctuating you may experience such issue where the request sometime times out; you can also try reading in fixed size buffer and will be able to see progress of download when your request fails

Comment: @Shubham Srivastava Network is good because I am in corporate network and it is proxy less. When you say fixed size buffer, you are indicating that I should create a large buffer size taking a highest size assumption, is it?

Comment: I mean make for example a 128 or 256kb buffer and download it 128kb at a time then you can log to see amount of data chunks received before it fails you can choose bigger buffer based on need

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Purpose I am trying to achieve here is , I am downloading docker images from Azure Blob Storage , suppose I am downloading an "Alpine" image it will be of very less size compared to the "Ubuntu" image I am trying to download , there is no fix  size . For small files it will working good.

Comment: Doing download in chunks will help you find out how much data is coming in and then you can see if the network inconsistencies are the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing packets from wireshark got to know it was getting disconnected from my side due to timeout as I am using go-swagger , I increased the timeout , in **configure.go** . GoSwagger provides in-built function for handling these scenarios  like TLS , Timeout. Below is code for reference.

```
// As soon as server is initialized but not run yet, this function will be called.
// If you need to modify a config, store server instance to stop it individually later, this is the place.
// This function can be called multiple times, depending on the number of serving schemes.
// scheme value will be set accordingly: "http", "https" or "unix"

func configureServer(s *http.Server, scheme, addr string) {
    s.WriteTimeout(time.Minute * 5)
}
```